# Publish a locally generated report on the server

Tags: java, html, jsp, web-applications

I have my web application running using a tomcat server on localhost:8080/myWebApp

Internally I accomplish a task of creating a report which is stored locally at "C:/project/myProject".

I can view the report by opening "C:/project/myProject/report.html" manually. I want to integrate this into my web application.

I tried writing a jsp file to open this "report.html" but that does not seem to work.

myJsp.jsp

```
<a href='file:///C:/project/myProject/report.html'>View Report</a>
```

This doesnt work.

Edit: I do not want to store the report in my webapp directory because it will be deleted when I build the new .war file and deploy it.

Comment: You must create the file in the path of the web application or you can also store the content in a database and create a page to load it.

Comment: Put `report.html` to your web root, and then write `<a href='/report.html'>View Report</a>`. Dont use absolute filesystem paths.

Answer (score 1):

I think you access the webpage is not from localhost.

the problem is

```
<a href='file:///C:/project/myProject/report.html'>View Report</a>
```

`href` is relative to the machine which access from (using the brower). so if access in localhost, you can get resource from `file:///C:/project/myProject/report.html` , but from some other machine , the resource `file:///C:/project/myProject/report.html` is not able to touch.

if you want to access the resource , you can easily publish content in web by any web server (nginx/apache/IIS/tomcat) or some file content service, and point the href there

Comment: I am publishing the content on the web using tomcat. I want it to work on my machine at this point of time. It does not matter if it cant be accessed from other machines.

Comment: what do you mean of the content , do you mean the myJsp.jsp or the report.html ?

Comment: myJsp.jsp is visible on the browser, with a hyper link "view report" which on click should open report.html
P.S: I'm a beginner

Comment: @user3305645 so this should work , <a href='file:///C:/project/myProject/report.html'>View Report</a> , otherwise , please open the link `file:///C:/project/myProject/report.html` directly in the brower.

Answer (score 0):

Either put that in your current application folder and access directly

```
<a href='report.html'>View Report</a>
```

Or go to that folder path using:

```
<a href='../../report.html'>View Report</a>
```

or try using your ip:

```
<a href='http://<ip address>:<port>/<folder_path>/report.html'>View Report</a>
```